# How does "cat << EOF | grep" work in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, here-document

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549836/2072269) to [How does "cat << EOF" work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash) on Stack Overflow, I get the first two points. But I don't get the third point **Pass multi-line string to a pipe in Bash**

> 3. Pass multi-line string to a pipe in Bash
>
>    ```
>     $ cat <<EOF | grep 'b' | tee b.txt
>     foo
>     bar
>     baz
>     EOF
>    ```

Since It have 3 word, 2 pipe character. Then I am not sure how to intrepret it.

Comment: Drop the leading space in the ```EOF``` line.

Comment: @RudiC I am not sure what does the first pipe ("|") character for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From your comment:

> I am not sure what does the first pipe ("|") character for?

The first `|` character connects the output of `cat` to the input of `grep`. `<<` redirects the *input* of `cat`; it's a totally independent redirection, similar to `<` in `cat <some_file | grep …`.

You may prefer `<<EOF cat | grep 'b' | tee b.txt` (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690)) because if you read this from left to right then it will strictly correspond to how the data flows: *here document* → `cat` → `grep` → `tee`.

Note all this can be done without `cat`:

```
<<EOF grep 'b' | tee b.txt
foo
bar
baz
EOF
```

(or `grep 'b' <<EOF | …`).

Comment: However, please note that some programs behave differently if STDIN or STDOUT is a pipe. In such a case, `cat < example1 | example2` would work differently than `example2 < example1`. A real-world example would be `ls | cat`.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, Can you help me with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685087/505362) question

Answer (score 7):

What you are using with `<< EOF` is a [**heredoc**](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

The multi-line string gets written to a temporary file and is then made the **stdin** of the `/bin/cat` process.
The output of `cat`, which is the multi-line string, gets piped to `grep` and its output in turn is piped to `tee`.

Answer (score 4):

As a further example of the heredoc syntax:

```bsh
cat <<EOF1 | cat /proc/self/fd/3 - 3<<EOF2 | cat /proc/self/fd/3 - 3<<EOF3  
foo
EOF1
bar
EOF2
baz 
EOF3
```

outputs

```
baz
bar
foo
```

One might think at first that after the heredoc redirection one needs to immediately provide the heredoc, but that's not the case. One can continue writing the command, and even provide further heredoc redirections. This means you can have your command in one place without the redirection forcing you to split it to after the possibly long heredocs.

Answer (score 3):

You have a pipeline consisting of three simple commands:

1. A `cat` command with a here document

   ```
   cat <<EOF
     foo
     bar
     baz
   EOF
   ```
2. `grep 'b'`
3. `tee b.txt`

The `<<EOF` is associated with the simple command; the *rest* of the here document begins on the next *physical* line. Here's an obfuscated, but equivalent, command:

```
cat <<EOF | grep 'b' |
foo
bar
baz
EOF
tee b.txt
```

The first physical line is *logically* continued, because a pipeline cannot end with a `|`. However, the rest of the here document takes precedence over the rest of the pipeline; the next command of the pipeline will be parsed after the here-document is terminated.

Comment: It definitely doesn't help that (as I write this) even the syntax highlighter gets confused about the rest of the line being part of the heredoc.

Comment: The syntax highlighter is based on regular expressions; shell is decidedly *not* a regular language.

Comment: Sure, but that's irrelevant to my point. What I meant is, it might be worth explicitly saying in your answer that the way this code gets highlighted is misleading about what counts as part of the here document.

Comment: I take it as a given that syntax highlighting should be ignored as a source of truth, since it will vary among editors and formatting libraries. It's fine as a reading aid, but should not be thought of as a syntax checker.

Comment: I agree, but most people who read the answer probably will not understand that - and perhaps more importantly, even if you know not to take syntax highlighting as a source of truth, the mere fact that it exists and is incorrect is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is redundant in `cat | grep` chain. It is a sign of newbies copy-pasting other newbies.

`grep` (or any other tool) could accept the input just fine without `cat`:

```
grep PATT <<EOF
...
EOF
```

Shell grammar allows specification of IO redirection before or after the command:

```
<<EOF grep OK - <(echo "OK 2")
OK 1
EOF
```

It prints (searching stdin from HERE-document, specified by `-`; then searching named pipe from process substitution, specified by `<()`):

```
(standard input):OK 1
/dev/fd/63:OK 2
```

You could have as many HERE-doc as you wish, just forward the data to different file descriptors, with duplicating redirection the latest "wins" (below prints `OK3`):

```
<<EOF1 <<EOF2 cat <<EOF3
OK1
EOF1
OK2
EOF2
OK3
EOF3
```

Example of opening stream 3, writing data to it and reading it later (notice syntax `<&N` for redirecting descriptor `N` to descriptor `0`, which is `stdin`):

```
exec 3<<EOF
> OK
> EOF

cat <&3
OK
```

There is a possibility to refer to file descriptors of the process via `proc` file system `/proc/self/fd/N` (make sure you understand what `self` is when forks processes!):

```bash
<<EOF cat | cat - /proc/self/fd/3 3<<EOF3 | cat - /proc/self/fd/4 4<<EOF4
> OK 1
> EOF
> OK 2
> EOF3
> OK 3
> EOF4
OK 1
OK 2
OK 3
```

Comment: "It is a sign of newbies copy-pasting other newbies." Hmmm… Could you notice some subtle difference between the output of cat file_a file_b | grep pattern and the one of grep pattern file_a file_b that could invite you to temper the vociferation of your disdain ?

Comment: `cat | CMD` is almost always an anti-pattern. `grep` acts differently when you supply file via CLI vs via stdin (like printing file name as a prefix): the behavior is adjustable via CLI options.

Comment: BTW I had not asked for whatever demonstration, I had only ventured the suggestion to appear less patronizing in your answer. :-P