# sed complicated script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to understand [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805282/15603477) that explains how to implement "pop" command to a file using `sed`.

I build some test data with

```
printf "Line #%2d\n" {1..7} >file
```

then run

```
sed -e \$$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file
```

I'm trying to figure out this `sed` command. Here what I came up with so far:

1. `-e`

> -e script, --expression=script
> add the script to the commands to be executed.

2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786712/15603477) explains about `/dev/stdout`.
3. `\n` means newline
4. `-i~`

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied).

I still cannot understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command creates a file with seven lines of text. This data is used by [the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805282) to illustrate the effect of the `sed` command, and it is written to a file called `file`.

Given a shell that understands `$'...'` ("C-strings") and that you use GNU `sed` (to understand `d}` as `d;}`), the second command returns the last line from the test data file on standard output and removes it from the file, backing up the original data in `file~` (backing up the original data to `file~` is what `-i~` does).

In the SO answer, the `sed` editing script is written on the command line as

```bsh
\$$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}'
```

This is a literal `$`, followed by a "C-string", `$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}'`.  The C-string quoting means `\n` will be expanded to a literal newline, which gives

```
${w/dev/stdout
;d}
```

... which is a sloppy way of writing the `sed` script

```
$ {
    w /dev/stdout
    d
}
```

This `sed` editing script passes all but the last line through unchanged to the output (which goes into the file `file` since the `-i` option is used).

The last line is written to `/dev/stdout` rather than to the default output (which is `file` in this case) using the `w` command, and then deleted using `d`.

The effect is that all lines but the last remain in (are written back to) `file` while the last line is produced on standard output (which will be connected to your terminal).

Comment: The first `$` is part of the `sed` script, as it's not inside the quotes, it is escaped. The second `$` is part of the shells ANSI-C quoting. You could also write: `'${w/dev/stdout'$'\n'';d}'` to make it clear that  the `$'...'` is only needed for the `\n`.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html . -i, --mime
             Causes the file command to output mime type strings rather
             than the more traditional human readable ones.  Thus it may
             say ‘text/plain; charset=us-ascii’ rather than “ASCII
             text”. Can your add reference link that explain `-i~ file`

Comment: @Mark `file` is the name of the input file, i.e. the file created by the first command in your question.  It is not the `file` _utility_.  This has nothing to do with mime-types. The name `file` is just used as a generic name for a file in this case.  I tried to make that clear in the first paragraph of my answer: "a file called `file`".  The `-i` option is an option to `sed`.

Comment: @they `~` normally refer to home directory [tilde]. I am not sure what does it mean? when it connect with `i`.

Comment: @Mark I've now added a clarification about `-i~` in the text. It is common to back up files before making changes to them, and `sed -i~` does this by copying the original data to a file with the original file's name with an added `~` at the end. If you try running the two commands in an otherwise emtpy directory, and look at the files created, it should be clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You got a good answer to the question you asked but FYI the best answer to "how to implement `pop` command to a file using sed" as in the question you referenced is "don't do that". I expect that question would have got that answer if it hadn't been quickly closed as unclear.

The following uses GNU awk instead of the GNU sed you're currently using, will work in any shell, and is hopefully much easier to understand:

```
$ awk -i inplace 'NR>1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{if (NR) print prev}' file
Line # 7

$ cat file
Line # 1
Line # 2
Line # 3
Line # 4
Line # 5
Line # 6
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace for more info on "inplace" editing with GNU awk.